# AWS: Multipart upload results in 403 Forbidden error even though single part upload works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

**CONTEXT:**
In my app, I have a feature that allows the user to upload a video. I noticed that when the users try to upload large videos, sometimes the upload fails.
After, I did a bit of research, I found-out for files larger than 100 Mb, I should use [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html).
So I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.altostra.com/blog/multipart-uploads-with-s3-presigned-url) to implement multipart upload in my app. And I reached **Stage Three**.

---

**PART 1: Previous single part upload works fine**
This is the implementation of a single part upload using *pre-signed urls*:

> BACKEND

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const REGION = "*************************"; //e.g. "us-east-1"
const BUCKET_NAME = "l****************";
AWS.config.update({ region: REGION });

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
});

var getVideoSignedUrl = async function (key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl(
      "putObject",
      {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        ContentType: "video/*",
        ACL: "public-read",
        Expires: 300,
      },
      (err, url) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(url);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};

exports.getVideoSignedUrl = getVideoSignedUrl;
```

> FRONTEND

```
export const getVideoPreSignedUrl = async () =>
  await axios.get("/api/profile/getVideoPreSignedURL");
export const uploadVideoFileToCloud = async (file) => {
  const { data: uploadConfig } = await getVideoPreSignedUrl();

  await axios.put(uploadConfig.url, file, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": file.type,
      "x-amz-acl": "public-read",
    },
    transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
      delete headers.common["Authorization"];
      return data;
    },
  });
};
```

---

**PART 2: Multipart upload which throws 403 forbidden error**

> BACKEND

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const REGION = "***********************"; //e.g. "us-east-1"
const BUCKET_NAME = "************************";
AWS.config.update({ region: REGION });

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
});

// ==========================================================
// Replacing getVideoSignedUrl with initiateMultipartUpload
// That would generate a presigned url for every part

const initiateMultipartUpload = async (object_name) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: object_name,
    ContentType: "video/*",
    ACL: "public-read",
    Expires: 300,
  };

  const res = await s3.createMultipartUpload(params).promise();

  return res.UploadId;
};

const generatePresignedUrlsParts = async (object_name, number_of_parts) => {
  const upload_id = await initiateMultipartUpload(object_name);
  const baseParams = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: object_name,
    UploadId: upload_id,
  };

  const promises = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < number_of_parts; index++) {
    promises.push(
      s3.getSignedUrlPromise("uploadPart", {
        ...baseParams,
        PartNumber: index + 1,
      })
    );
  }

  const res = await Promise.all(promises);

  const signed_urls = {};

  res.map((signed_url, i) => {
    signed_urls[i] = signed_url;
  });
  return signed_urls;
};

exports.initiateMultipartUpload = initiateMultipartUpload;
exports.generatePresignedUrlsParts = generatePresignedUrlsParts;
```

> FRONTEND

This is where the error occurs. **See** `const resParts = await Promise.all(promises)`

```
export const getMultiPartVideoUploadPresignedUrls = async (number_of_parts) => {
  const request_params = {
    params: {
      number_of_parts,
    },
  };
  return await axios.get(
    "/api/profile/get_multi_part_video_upload_presigned_urls",
    request_params
  );
};

// Using multipart upload

export const uploadVideoFileToCloud = async (video_file, dispatch) => {
  // Each chunk is 100Mb
  const FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 100_000_000;
  let video_size = video_file.size;
  let video_size_in_mb = Math.floor(video_size / 1000000);

  const number_of_parts = Math.floor(video_size_in_mb / 100) + 1;

  const response = await getMultiPartVideoUploadPresignedUrls(number_of_parts);
  const urls = response.data;
  console.log(
    " ~ file: profileActions.js ~ line 654 ~ uploadParts ~ urls",
    urls
  );
  // async function uploadParts(file: Buffer, urls: Record<number, string>) {
  // const axios = Axios.create()
  // delete axios.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"];

  const keys = Object.keys(urls);
  const promises = [];

  for (const indexStr of keys) {
    const index = parseInt(indexStr);
    const start = index * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE;
    const end = (index + 1) * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE;
    const blob =
      index < keys.length
        ? video_file.slice(start, end)
        : video_file.slice(start);
    console.log(
      " ~ file: profileActions.js ~ line 691 ~ uploadParts ~ urls[index]",
      urls[index]
    );

    console.log(
      " ~ file: profileActions.js ~ line 682 ~ uploadParts ~ blob",
      blob
    );
    const upload_params = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": video_file.type,
        "x-amz-acl": "public-read",
      },
      transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        delete headers.common["Authorization"];
        return data;
      },
    };
    const axios_request = axios.put(urls[index], blob, upload_params);
    promises.push(axios_request);
    console.log(
      " ~ file: profileAction.helper.js ~ line 117 ~ uploadParts ~ promises",
      promises
    );
  }
  // Uploading video parts
  // This throws the 403 forbidden error
  const resParts = await Promise.all(promises);
  // This never gets logged
  console.log(
    " ~ file: profileAction.helper.js ~ line 124 ~ uploadParts ~ resParts",
    resParts
  );

  // return resParts.map((part, index) => ({
  //   ETag: (part as any).headers.etag,
  //   PartNumber: index + 1
  // }))
};
```

### This is the error that's logged:
[image]

**PART 3: AWS Bucket & CORS policy:**

1. CORS Policy:

   [
   {
   "AllowedHeaders": [
   "*"
   ],
   "AllowedMethods": [
   "PUT",
   "POST",
   "GET"
   ],
   "AllowedOrigins": [
   "*"
   ],
   "ExposeHeaders": [],
   "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
   }
   ]
2. Bucket policy hasn't been changed since I created the bucket and it's still empty by default:

   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
   "Sid": "Statement1",
   "Principal": {},
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": [],
   "Resource": []
   }
   ]
   }

[image]

So maybe I should add something here?
I also have all of these **unchecked:**
[image]

---

**NOTES:**

1. I tested multipart upload with files smaller and larger than 100 Mb. And it always throws the 403 forbidden error.
2. I don't understand why I would get forbidden error if the single part upload works just fine. In other words, the upload is allowed and if both single part and multipart upload are using the same credentials, then that **forbidden** error should not occur.
3. I have a piece of code that shows me the progress of the upload. And I see the upload progressing. And the error seems to occur **AFTER** the upload of **EACH PART** is done:
   [image]
   [image]